# Opening the same page multiple times in different tabs using window.open

Tags: javascript, window.open, window.location

I am trying to automate a very manual workflow. To that end, I need to open a specific page containing

```
workflow_history
```

in the URL. I need to open it 4 times in 4 different tabs.

I want to automate this in a Tampermonkey script to reduce clicking.

I can't simply save these for links in a bookmark bar folder and open all the links using right-click > open all. The links are always different (entries in a database), but they do always contain

```
workflow_history
```

This is what I have:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
var isWorkflow = /workflow_history/.test(window.location.href);
if (isWorkflow) {
window.open(location.href)
}
})();
```

The above code results in an endless loop where more and more tabs open until the browser crashes.

I need the script to only open the same page 4 times. How can I stop the loop after 4 iterations?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a somewhat hacky solution:

```
var allLinks = document.links; 
$('body').click(function(){
window.open(allLinks.item(12));
window.open(allLinks.item(13));
window.open(allLinks.item(14));
window.open(allLinks.item(14));
});
```

This opens the 4 necessary links in the tool I am using on just one click.
Note that the numbers of the links (12-14) are specific to the page in my tool.